# Visual Studio 2017 Error in Test Property Page

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017

There is an issue with my Visual Studio / Test Property Page. Which is I guess one of the root causes to not discovering any of my tests, in any of my projects. So this means it is not related to one Project, or to one nuget package on the projects. I am not sure when the issue first occurred, but I am suspecting, after some Visual Studio updates.
After following some of the possible solutions on SO, related to the Test Explorer, the tests itself and the Test property Page. I found the following:
[image]
*When I go in Tools -> Options -> Test. I have the error shown above.*

Error: "An error occurred loading this property page"

- It is not an issue of missing nuget packages. Because it is happening in all of my projects.
- The latest .NET framework is installed
- All of the questions on SO, related to this topic, didn't have something that could help me solve this issue. Unless I missed something, which is quite possible.
- Re installation of Visual Studio itself didn't help. The issue persists.
- Deleting VS test cache files DEL %TEMP%\VisualStudioTestExplorerExtensions
- Restarting VS
- Test -> Test Settings -> Default processor architecture is set to x86

Comment: I don't think this question belongs to SO. (Also c# tag is unnecessary)

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research, I find a case which has the same error message with yours. The issue was resolved by running “devenv /setup” in Visual Studio 2017 Command Prompt.

I’m not sure if this works on you machine. Please try it, I do hope it is helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I did already try that option, and it did not help me.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem in Visual Studio 2019. I was helped by the "Visual Studio 2019 Command Prompt" with the "devenv /updateconfiguration" command. After that, when I started the Visual Studio, there in the settings the Test tab worked.

I spotted the solution here, but did only step 4:
https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/9421#issuecomment-191895696

Answer (score 0):

### It worked for me! (On VS 2019 version)

1. Open Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019 Preview
2. Run devenv /resetuserdata

Comment: I would just like to point out this is a rather 'destructive' command. It wipes out all your user settings for visual studio